# Algorithm for Conway's Game of Life in potentially infinite grid in Python

Tags: python, game-of-life, cellular-automata

I implemented a program for computing Conway's Game of Life iterations in Python starting from an initial grid configuration given as input. It is intended to handle arbitrarily large grids. I tried to be as concise and efficient as possible and it seems to be working appropriately. Are there any improvements I could make? I'm specially interested in advice on more appropriate data structures (other than set and defaultdict). Thanks.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Tuple, Set

class ConwaysAutomaton:
    def __init__(self, pattern: Set[Tuple[int, int]]):   
        # Store all alive cells in current iteration     
        self.alive = pattern 
    
    def update(self):
        # The dict's keys are cells, represented by a tuple
        # with their coordinates in the grid(row, column),
        # and the values are the number of neighbours they
        # currently have. 
        # It stores the set of all cells with potential to stay alive
        # or to come to life (because they have neighbours).
        hot_cells = defaultdict(int)

        for alive in self.alive:
            hot_cells[(alive[0]-1,  alive[1]-1)] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0]-1, alive[1])] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0]-1, alive[1]+1)] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0], alive[1]-1)] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0], alive[1]+1)] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0]+1, alive[1]-1)] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0]+1, alive[1])] += 1
            hot_cells[(alive[0]+1, alive[1]+1)] += 1

        new_alive = set()
        for candidate in hot_cells.keys():
            # From Wikipedia:
            # Any live cell with two or three live neighbours survives.
            # Any dead cell with three live neighbours becomes a live cell.
            # All other live cells die in the next generation. 
            # Similarly, all other dead cells stay dead.  
            if (candidate in self.alive and hot_cells[candidate] in [2, 3]) \
                or (candidate not in self.alive and hot_cells[candidate] == 3):               
                    new_alive.add(candidate)
        self.alive = new_alive  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os, time
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    os.system('clear')

    #Pi-heptomino
    #   ooo
    #   o o
    #   o o
    pattern = {(25, 25), (25, 26), (25, 27), (26, 25), (26, 27), (27, 25), (27, 27)}

    iteration = 0
    automaton = ConwaysAutomaton(pattern)
    while True:
        clear()
        print("Iteration #", iteration)
        for row in range(50):
            for col in range(50):
                print('#' if (row, col) in automaton.alive else ' ', end = '')
            print()
        input()
        automaton.update()
        iteration += 1
```

Comment: Seems perfect to me

Comment: @QuasiStellar thank you! appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I have just a few recommendations and a question:

#### Use Docstrings

You currently have no Docstrings. Some of the comments in method `ConwaysAutomation.update` could serve to document what the method's purpose is. For example:

```py
class ConwaysAutomaton:
    """Class to implement Conway's Game of Life"""
    
    def __init__(self, pattern: Set[Tuple[int, int]]):
        """
        Arguments
        ---------
        pattern : Set
        
        A set of tuples representing the coordinates of live cells.
        """
        
        self.alive = pattern 
    
    def update(self):
        """Compute the next generation of live cells.
        It stores the set of all cells with potential to stay alive
        or to come to life (because they have neighbours).
        """
        
        # The dict's keys are cells, represented by a tuple
        # with their coordinates in the grid(row, column),
        # and the values are the number of neighbours they
        # currently have. 
        hot_cells = defaultdict(int)
        ...
```

#### Substitute `collections.Counter` for `collections.defaultdict`

You currently have:

```py
hot_cells = defaultdict(int)
```

Consider instead:

```py
from collections import Counter
...
hot_cells = Counter()
```

The rest of the code remains unchanged but now it is immediately clear that the integer values of this dictionary hold counts.

#### Make Attribute `alive` Private

You currently have client code that is accessing `self.alive` assuming its implementation, which could change in the future. Suggest that this attribute is "private" by renaming it to `_alive` and then create a method `is_alive` that the client calls instead:

```py
        
    def is_alive(self, coordinate: Tuple[int, int]) -> bool:
        """Is the cell at the passed coordinate alive?"""

        return coordinate in self._alive
```

#### Question

You have:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os, time
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    os.system('clear')
    ...
```

Invoking `clear()` appears to clear the screen on Windows, where the *cls* console command exists for that purpose. But then you call `os.system('clear')`, which won't work on Windows. So I am not clear why you have that.  **You could test the platform and define `clear` to issue either a `cls` or `clear` command accordingly.**

Comment: Thanks for you reply! About your question, I probably messed up that snippet after copying it from somewhere else. After some research, I found out that os.system("cls||clear") does the job. Thanks for noticing though. Also liked the suggestion of using Counter instead of defaultdict. In this case they're indeed interchangeable, and Counter really improves semantics!